# How to disable gradle in cordova?

Tags: android, windows, node.js, cordova, gradle

I Upgraded my cordova from 4.3 to 5.0.0 few days ago.
After that I'm facing with various errors and build fails!
Every time I want to build my app, I have to follow this long instruction to get successful build:

- `cordova platform remove android`
- `cordova platform add android`
- exit and reopen node.js command prompt as administrator
- `cordova build android`

I want to pull out my hairs!

I think problem is from gradle. Is there any way to disable gradle in Cordova?

**Update:**

Sample error message:

```
D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app>cordova build android --debug
Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Projects\funny-app\
funny-app\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\Projects\funny-app\fu
nny-app
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\platforms\android\cordova\build
.bat --debug
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_25
Running: D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug
 -b D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.
daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
> Executor Singleton not started

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.813 secs

D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:12
6
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\
platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\platf
orms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\plat
forms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: D:\Projects\funny-app\funny-app\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Comm
and failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cord
ova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Comment: can you include the error that the console is showing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force CLI to use Ant during a build with the following command:

`cordova build android -- --ant`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution was to run `cordova clean`.